# Is there a way to refresh a file in C without opening/closing it?

Tags: c

I initially open a file using fopen().
I then read from the file (using fgetc()) numerous times throughout the program, which aims to loop/poll at speeds under 1 ms.
While these reads are happening, the value I read in this file is subject to change.

However, I don't see the changes when reading the file, further investigation resulted in it outputting its initial value despite being changed.

I do know one workaround is to cyclically open/close the file, but this is making quite a few system calls which makes it slower/inefficient.

Comment: The file stream is probably buffered, by default. You may want to try disabling buffering, using the function [`setbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf), for example `setbuf( fp, NULL );`.

Comment: Make sure whatever is writing to the file is writing to the same *file* instead of only the same *file name*: some programs write to a separate file and rename over the old one, for various reasons.

Comment: The standard I/O library reads a buffer full of data from the file (perhaps 512 bytes, perhaps 1024 or 4096 — not that it matters much) and then doles out what it read one character at a time.  If the content of the file changes between when the buffer was read and the character was returned, you'll not see the changes.  You'll see what was in the file when the buffer full of data was read.  You may end up choosing to use the `read()` and `write()` system calls instead of the standard I/O package, but not using buffering has an impact on efficiency, but you need accuracy more than efficiency.